# Does turn relay support TCP connection between peer and turn server?

Tags: webrtc, turn, ice

Assuming this is my usage scenario:

`Client` and `Peer A` cannot connect directly, and now `Client` is assigned a port for relay through its own `Turn server`.

I know that `Client` can connect to `Turn server` via TCP.

What I want to known is whether `Peer A` can connect to this relay port by TCP?

```
                                       Peer A
                                       Server-Reflexive    +---------+
                                       Transport Address   |         |
                                       192.0.2.150:32102   |         |
                                           |              /|         |
                         TURN              |            / ^|  Peer A |
      Client's           Server            |           /  ||         |
      Host Transport     Transport         |         //   ||         |
      Address            Address           |       //     |+---------+
   198.51.100.2:49721  192.0.2.15:3478     |+-+  //     Peer A
              |            |               ||N| /       Host Transport
              |   +-+      |               ||A|/        Address
              |   | |      |               v|T|     203.0.113.2:49582
              |   | |      |               /+-+
   +---------+|   | |      |+---------+   /              +---------+
   |         ||   |N|      ||         | //               |         |
   | TURN    |v   | |      v| TURN    |/                 |         |
   | Client  |----|A|-------| Server  |------------------|  Peer B |
   |         |    | |^      |         |^                ^|         |
   |         |    |T||      |         ||                ||         |
   +---------+    | ||      +---------+|                |+---------+
                  | ||                 |                |
                  | ||                 |                |
                  +-+|                 |                |
                     |                 |                |
                     |                 |                |
            Client's                   |             Peer B
            Server-Reflexive     Relayed             Transport
            Transport Address    Transport Address   Address
            192.0.2.1:7000       192.0.2.15:50000    192.0.2.210:49191

                                  Figure 1
```

Comment: yes, you can configure your TURN server to support TCP connections, and you can disable UDP to make sure it will use TCP.

Comment: @ChristianFritz Thank you very much.  Now is the actual situation can not be established, my Turn server is coturn, the client uses webrtc@android-sdk, do not know is the aspect needs to be configured to work.

Comment: @ChristianFritz This question has been close by someone. Would you please review the related question and give some other comments? thank you very much!

Comment: The setup you are looking for is not supported as explained in the other question. Both clients can connect to their respective TURN servers and allocations over TCP, then those allocations use UDP to send packets to each other.

Comment: @PhilippHancke thank yo very much.